# python shell script execution that passes environment to the parent

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables

So I know how `subprocess` works and use it a lot, but I've run into a strange issue. I need to execute an export of some environment variables. The reason is that some program (black-box) executes a program that seems like it runs in a subshell, so it doesn't have access to the environment variables but it has access to all my files.

I can't hard code the environment variables so I want to `source` or `.` the file that has the `export` commands in it. However, if I `source` or `.` that file in a subprocess, it won't make any difference to its parent process. In which case I either need some function besides `subprocess` that can execute shell commands without creating a subprocess, if that exists. Another issue is that a subprocess doesn't have the proper permissions to read the file.

And copying the environment variables via `os` isn't really possible either.

Does anything besides `subprocess` exist? Or is there some other kind of workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the simplest solution consists in creating a new shell script (let's call it `run_black_box.sh`) which sources the setup script (let's assume it is named `setup.sh`) to initialize the environment and then calls the black_box program.

Here is a possible content of `run_black_box.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash
source setup.sh
black_box
```

The you can pass `run_black_box.sh` to `subprocess` for execution.